# Indexed query not optimized enough

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to optimize the following query and only been able to chip of 10 seconds. I have tried to apply non clustered index on foreign key table columns that are involved in the joins. 
Could somebody let me know what I could do to make the query faster ?

```
select
    c.companyId, 
    c.companyName, 
    c.city, 
    cst.companyStatusTypeName,
    ct.companyTypeName,
    sc.simpleIndustryDescription,
    c.officeFaxValue, 
    c.officePhoneValue, 
    c.streetAddress,
    c.streetAddress2, 
    c.yearFounded,
    c.zipCode,
    c.webpage,
    rep.templateTypeName, 
    rcg.isoCountry2,
    rs.abbreviation
from ciqCompany c
    inner join ciqCompanyStatusType cst on cst.companystatustypeid = c.companystatustypeid
    inner join ciqCompanyType ct on ct.companyTypeId = c.companyTypeId
    inner join refReportingTemplateType rep on rep.templateTypeId = c.reportingtemplateTypeId
    inner join refCountryGeo rcg on c.countryId = rcg.countryId
    inner join refState rs on rs.stateId = c.stateId
    inner join ciqSimpleIndustry sc on sc.simpleIndustryId = c.simpleIndustryId
```

**Execution Plan**

[image]

**Table definition**

[image]

Comment: Can you show DDL and an EXPLAIN please? Otherwise, we're probably just going to recommend doing stuff at random.

Comment: Without table definitions, indexes, execution plan this is like calling the mechanic and saying "I have a blue car, how do I make it faster?".

Comment: Sorry updated the post to include the execution plan and table definition

Comment: What does the clustered index (PK_CIQ_COMPANY) you created look like (order & columns involved?) Does it really have all the keys from the other tables and and not CompanyID?  I would think you'd want a CompanyID in one index and all the FKs for CIQ_COMPANY in another.

Comment: @Tom, Please include all tables definitions and count.

Answer (score 0):

Try building the columnstore index:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-data-warehouse

Comment: Isnt this more for 2016. I am using Sql 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the execution plan, I noticed the key lookups are taking up the most time.
Try creating an index with all the columns in that query.
Or try using a included columns in your index.

some helpfull reading: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/

Comment: Sorry didnt get what your meant ? creating an index with all the columns in that query.

Comment: In the link i provided, there's an explanation about it but basically it's like this: in the execution plan go to Properties > Output List and click on the ellipsis (...) to see what columns are being queried. Then create a non-clustered index on the ciqCompany table that encompasses all the columns in the Output List

Comment: I tried covered index. It took even more time that usual. here is the script CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_companyCoveringIndex on XpressFeed_Dev.dbo.ciqCompany(companyStatusTypeId,companyTypeId,reportingTemplateTypeId,countryId,stateId,simpleIndustryId) 
INCLUDE (companyName,city,officeFaxValue,officePhoneValue,streetAddress2,yearFounded,zipCode,webpage)

Comment: Only managed to read this today. It shouldn't take longer, can you post the execution plan with that index? Maybe there is another bottleneck on that query